# How to retrieve data from wearable device( specifically Xiamoi Smartwatch) using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, xiaomi

I am trying to develop a system that consists of a smartwatch and a companion app. The companion app will be developed in Flutter. Do you know any way to send the smartwatch data(Heart rate, stress level, steps, locations, etc.) to the Flutter application?
If you know any SDK I will help a lot.

Comment: We get a lot of questions like these. Sometimes data like Heart rate will be freely available through a characteristic, just use a generic BLE scanner such as [nRFConnect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to analyze the smartwatch. All the other data is most likely hidden behind some kind of proprietary characteristic and you can only access it using the manufacturers app.

Comment: So by using bluetooth scanning library i may be able to receive some data from the device?

Comment: You must already use a bluetooth scanning library such as [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue), flutter does not offer Bluetooth functionality on it's own. I suggest you start by using the BLE scanner app I suggested and try to figure out how to retrieve your data

Comment: Okey thanks alot i will try it out and see how thinks goes on, thanks again